# "The remote server returned an error: (404)" in desktop application for framework 3.5 [solved]

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, desktop-application

I am using an API for my desktop application. The application runs on dot.net framework 3.5.

I have an API which runs perfectly, but when i call the API from the desktop application, there is an error:

> "The remote server returned an error: (404)"

But my API runs with no problem. I have two parameters, which will passed in the URL.

Here is my Code :

```
string url = "http://localhost:58167/api/Project/";
string data = "65354/19216882";
string response;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
{
     client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
     response = client.downloadstring(url, "POST", data);
}
```

How can I solve the problem?

**EDIT:**
Here is the code that illustrates how the API looks like:

```
    // GET api/Project
    public string GetProjects(string key, string IP)
    {
        string sql = "";
        string en = "";
        if (IP == "19216")
            sql = "garbage1";
        if (IP == "19882")
            sql = " garbage2";
        if (IP == "181249")
            sql = " garbage3";
        if (IP == "85206")
            sql = " garbage4";
        if (IP == "87249")
            sql = " garbage5";

        en = CryptorEngine.Encrypt(sql, key);
        return en;
    }
```

update  solved code:

```
string url = "http://localhost:58167/api/Project/";
string data = "65354/19216882";
string response;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
{
     client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
     response = client.downloadstring(url, "POST", data);
}
```

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to capture the working request that is sent to the API, and to capture the failing request that is sent to the API. Compare the two using a diff tool like WinMerge and you will find the answer :)

Comment: So you have a server that has API and listening on port `58167` and endpoint `/api/Project/`. You are sending HTTP message of type "POST" to it and the server replies with 404 - page not found. Correct?

Comment: Please show us also code for the server endpoint where the values (path for `/api/Project/` and port number) are visible.

Comment: // GET api/Project
public string GetProjects(string a, string b)
        {
             string a= "something";
             string b="something1";
              result = a+b;
            return result;
        }
it's just sample code. but orginal code almost same.

Comment: @percy Your sample code won't compile - you are redeclaring `a` and `b`. Also, your sample method takes two parameters (`a` and `b`) but you are not supplying them anywhere in your client - or, at least, not in a way I recognize. Can I recommend you produce an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate your problem? It's very difficult for us to help you if you are not showing us the real issue...

Comment: I update my api project code in question. hope it will help

Comment: Is the server running?

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar yes. server is running.

Comment: And have you tried it in isolation?  with the URL you are calling from the desktop?

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar no. haven't tried any isolation. can you help me with how can i isolate?

Comment: What I mean is, have you tried the EXACT url against the server to ensure it wokrs

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar yes. url against server is exactly look like.

Comment: Your client is making a `POST` request, but the comment before the API action suggests it should be a `GET` request.

Comment: We don't put answers in the question.  Accept a posted answer or post your own.

Comment: @LarsTech ok. got it. will do. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all guys. i got my solved and i updated my update code in question. just change uploadstring to downloadstring . and bingo.. it works. –

update solved code:

```
string url = "http://localhost:58167/api/Project/";
string data = "65354/19216882";
string response;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
{
     client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
     response = client.downloadstring(url, "POST", data);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

try add attribute routing to your API

```
 Route[("~/api/Project/{key}/{ip}")]
 public string GetProjects(string key, string IP)
```

your code

```
string url = "http://localhost:58167/api/Project/65354/19216882";
string response;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
{
     client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
     response = client.UploadString(url, "GET");
}
```

if you don't have control over api

you can use the existing action

```
Route[("~/api/Project")]
public string GetProjects(string key, string IP)
```

code

```
string url = "http://localhost:58167/api/Project?key=65354&IP=19216882";
    
string response;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
{
     client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
     response = client.UploadString(url, "GET");
}
```

if you still need to use POST you have to fix the acion

```
public class ViewModel
{
 public  string Key {get; set;}
  public string IP  {get; set;}
}

 Route[("~/api/Project")]
 public string GetProjects([FromBody]ViewModel model)
```

Comment: used the attribute routing in my API and try first one in my code. But Still getting error 
"The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type."

Comment: @percy Add [FromBody] to the input parameter

Comment: Route[("~/api/Project/{key}/{ip}")]
 public string GetProjects([FromBody]  string key, [FromBody]  string IP)

like that?

Comment: @percy  No , it's not.  see the last line in my answer

Comment: thank you all guys. i got my solved and i updated my update code in question. just change uploadstring to downloadstring . and bingo.. it works.